# Export as an executable jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, maven, executable-jar

I have an maven eclipse project which I want to export as an executable jar file from command line. I have external library jars also in the project. How can I get the executable jar file inclusive of all library jars from command line?

**EDIT::**
Now there is a challenge.There are actually two projects.One is `PROJECT` and other is `Project_Framework`. Both these folders are having `pom.xml`.The dependencies are written in `pom.xml` in `PROJECT` folder. `PROJECT` is dependen t on `Project_Framework`. After adding `maven-shade` plugin it is saying it cannot find the snapshot dependency of `Project_Framework`. How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable jar with dependencies using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna: There is a challenge for me in this question.There are actually two projects.One is `PROJECT` and other is `Project_Framework`. Both these folders are having pom.xml.The dependencies are written in pom.xml in PROJECT folder. Where should I add the plugin? This is indeed confusing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `maven-shade-plugin` to add all dependecies to your jar.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Then Change directory to `PROJECT_FRAMEWORK`.Then type

```
mvn install
```

Then, again change directory to `PROJECT`. If you have added it, you can simply run

`mvn package`.

Comment: Don't use acient versions of [maven-shade-plugin. Current version is 2.3](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Comment: @khmarbaise: All my dependencies are written in `pom.xml`. So I believe there is no need of a plugin.I am expecting a command which  should do it.

Comment: @NevinRaj You need the plugin. maven do not include jar files to the artefact. This will do the plugin

Comment: @Jens So this plugin should be added in the `pom.xml`. Right?

Comment: @NevinRaj Yes you have to add it.

Comment: @Jens: Now there is a challenge.There are actually two projects.One is `PROJECT` and other is `Project_Framework`. Both these folders are having `pom.xml`.The dependencies are written in `pom.xml` in `PROJECT` folder. Where should I add the plugin.

Comment: @NevinRaj in `PROJECT`

Comment: @Jens Does the `maven-compiler` plugin also do the job of `maven-shade` plugin?

Comment: @NevinRaj No. maven-compiler only compiles your sources.

Comment: @Jens : I have written only a `maven-compiler-plugin` but when i run the command `mvn package` it runs the entire program.

Comment: @NevinRaj it compiles yor program. But it not includes third party jars.